# Stress test in a Silverlight application, which consumes data from a WCF DataService then exposes data from a SQLServer Database

Tags: sql-server, testing, silverlight, wcf-data-services, stress-testing

I´m deploying a Silverlight application, which consumes data from a WCF DataService then exposes data from a SQLServer Database. Everytyhing works fine, but I´d like to make some stress tests. It´s the first time I have done this and I have some doubts:

1- I´ve seem some tools or programmatic ways to tests WCF services, all of them make calls to the service (sometimes asynchronously) from a console or windows application. Are these tests reliable in my case? Shouldn´t I test my service from a Silverlight UI? Or is there no difference?

2- Can someone recommend any specific (and maybe free) tools/ways for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stress test the web service. If the web service can handle concurrent requests. There should not be issue with calling layer (Silver Light App)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/02/05/howto-performance-test-asp-net-web-services-using-vsts.aspx